# string formatting from file

Tags: java, file, formatting

I am trying to format a file in java. I am reading a file, separated by commas and trying to get it into columnar form. Any suggestions how I can fix this? The text file contains:

```
1, Short line, A, 14323, Hello
4, A litter longer, L, 455, Alright
6, Another line that that is a a little longer, X, 4432, TT
10, This is the biggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggest line, T, 543, OKOKOK
```

I am trying to make it look like this:

```
1.  Short line                                               A         14323       Hello
4.  A litter longer                                          L         455         Alright
6.  Another line that that is a a little longer              X         4432        TT
10. This is the biggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggest line     T         543         OKOKOK
```

My output looks like this:

```
1.                                            Short line       A     14323  Hello 
4.                                       A litter longer       L     455    Alright 
6.               Another line that that is a a little longer   X     4432   TT 
10.   This is the biggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggest line     T     543    OKOKOK
```

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
public class trash {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader f = new FileReader("Question.txt");
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
            String read = b.readLine();
            while (read != null) {
                int index = read.indexOf(",");
                String newStringRead = read.substring(index+1);
                String sub = read.substring(0,index+1);
                sub = sub.replace(",",".");
                newStringRead = newStringRead.replace((read.substring(0,index+1))," \t");
                newStringRead = newStringRead.replace(",", "\t");
                System.out.printf("%2s %70s %n",sub,newStringRead);
                read = b.readLine(); 
            }
            b.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("cant find file");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Please** don't *deface* your question by editing out all of the content.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and a [`try-with-resources` close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). And, I would use [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to parse the line. Then your format `String` needs a `-` (*minus sign* **before** the *width*) to left align. Something like,

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop/stackQuestion.txt"))) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] arr = line.split(",\\s*");
        System.out.printf("%-3s %-56s %-9s %-11s %s%n", arr[0] + ".",
                arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("cant find file");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which I ran with your provided file, and got (the requested)

```
1.  Short line                                               A         14323       Hello
4.  A litter longer                                          L         455         Alright
6.  Another line that that is a a little longer              X         4432        TT
10. This is the biggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggest line     T         543         OKOKOK
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `%-70s` in printf to make it left justified.

Example:
`printf("'%5s'", "Hi");`
The above will print '   Hi'

`printf("'%-5s'", "Hi");`
The above will print 'Hi   '